# Rspec + Unit Testing for Scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

```
expected: "SELECT `renewals`.* FROM `renewals` LEFT JOIN customers on renewals.customer_id = customers.id LEFT JOIN agents on customers.agent_id = agents.id WHERE agents.id = 103 and customers.status_id = 4 AND renewals.customer_id IN ()"
     got: "SELECT `renewals`.* FROM `renewals` LEFT JOIN customers ON renewals.customer_id = customers.id LEFT JOIN agents ON customers.agent_id = agents.id WHERE agents.id = 103 and customers.status_id = 4 AND renewals.customer_id IN ()"
(compared using ==)
```

I don't know why it's failing

Update:

```
  it "for_agent_renewal_between" do
    from          = Time.now - 10
    to            = Time.now + 10
    agent         = Agent.first
    renewals      = Renewal.where("ends_at BETWEEN '#{from.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}' AND '#{to.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}'")
    customer_ids  = renewals.collect{|renewal| renewal.customer_id}.uniq.join(",")
    expect(Renewal.for_agent_renewal_between(agent, Time.now - 10, Time.now + 10).to_sql).to eq(Renewal.joins("LEFT JOIN customers on renewals.customer_id = customers.id LEFT JOIN agents on customers.agent_id = agents.id WHERE agents.id = #{agent.id} and customers.status_id = 4 AND renewals.customer_id IN (#{customer_ids})").to_sql)
  end
```

Please Help me

Comment: Are you using a literal comparison? Could you post the test you are using.

Comment: @liamneesonsarmsauce check updates

Comment: Well since you are doing a literal comparison, you need to capitalize the 'on' strings in the query.

Comment: same problem after change 'on' TO 'ON'

Comment: I get same expected and got but don't know why it's failing

Comment: your code refers to dates... but i don't see them in the resulting sql. I point this out because dates can cause tricky difference due to being a millisecond out.

Comment: This may not be the best way to approach testing this sort of functionality.  Your test is very tied to the internals of how Rails works (and is probably more testing Rails itself).  You'd probably be better off unit testing this as a black box by creating some data, and then asserting that the scope returns the records you expect.